# im trying to use swiper but it's not working

Tags: swiper.js

im trying to use swiperjs but it's not working,even though im copying and past it from one of the Swiper demos.
./src/UI/swiper/PaginationSwiper.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper' in 'C:\Users\atozgram\Desktop\Jackson\front\src\UI\swiper'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because they did some stuff and you need newest node/npm, otherwise it will not install swipper succesfully, try to install 6.* version instead of 7.

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871